# Introducing blank lines separating matched sections

Tags: bash, sed

I have this bash function that prints lines between `Mode: org` and `# End of org`. I would like for matched sections to be separated by a blank line.

```
capture ()
{
 local efile="$1"
 
 local charcl begorg endorg
   charcl_ere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|\/\/)[[:space:]]*'
   charcl_bre='^[[:space:]]*\([#;!]\+\|@c\|\/\/\)[[:space:]]*'

   begorg="${charcl_bre}"'Mode: org$'
   endorg="${charcl_bre}"'# End of org$'

   mdr='^Mode: org$' ; edr='^# End of org$'
   
   sed -n "/$begorg/,/$endorg/ s/$charcl_bre//p" "$efile" |
    sed "/$mdr\|$edr/d"
}
```

This is the input

```
cat /home/flora/docs/recnotes.txt
   ## Mode: org
   #  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
   #  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
   #  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
   #  prefix `-'.
   ## # End of org

     ;; Mode: org
     ;  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
     ;  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
     ;  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
     ;  prefix `-'.
     ;; # End of org
 
       @c Mode: org
       @c  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
       @c  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
       @c  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
       @c  prefix `-'.
       @c # End of org
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed by *lines between* that you didn't mean including the lines with `Mode: org` and `# End of org`. You didn't specify that. Try:

```
perl -nlE'$p=/Mode: org/?1:/# End of org/?0*say$":$p&&$p+say' recnotes.txt
```

If it's important to avoid the empty separation line at the end, try:

```
perl -nlE'$p=/Mode: org/?1:/# End of org/?0*do{eof||say("")}:$p&&$p+say' r.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a straightforward way using

```
   sed -n "/$begorg/,/$endorg/ s/$charcl_bre//p" "$efile" |
    sed "/$mdr/d" | sed "s/$edr//"
```